# How to use jekyll to write a documentation of a project?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, project

I am writting a documentation for my project. I have done my project in python. But I choose [jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) to write down the documentation. But I didn't found any helpful documentation. There is lots of basic question still moving around me. Such as how to generate template in jekyll etc. Guys please suggest me any help full documentation or share your idea on documentation using jkeyll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jekyll is very blog-oriented. It can be used to generate static html pages, but it isn't ideal for documenting a software project (unless you intend to document it with a blog).

If your project is hosted on github, you will probably be better off by using github's wiki, which is fairly advanced now.

If you still want to generate documentation automatically, there are better solutions out there - [pydoc](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html) is one, but there are others, like [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/), or the newest arrival, [Dexy](http://blog.dexy.it).

Answer (score 37):

Now in 2014 there are some templates, I'm looking at

- http://bruth.github.io/jekyll-docs-template/

  - example http://modeltree.harvest.io/ref/lookup-syntax.html
- https://github.com/clojurewerkz/docslate

  - example http://clojuremongodb.info/
  - http://blog.clojurewerkz.org/blog/2013/06/15/how-we-document-our-projects-with-clojurewerkz-docslate/
- https://github.com/untyped/jekyll-docs

  - example ?? https://mynaweb.com/help/quick-start

2015 adding:

- https://github.com/tomjohnson1492/jekyll-doc from the answer of from Tom.

I think there should be others, but don't know.

Comment: I am developing a simple template for this purpose https://aksakalli.github.io/jekyll-doc-theme/

Answer (score 12):

I'm developing a jekyll theme for tech docs here: https://github.com/tomjohnson1492/documentation-theme-jekyll.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [mkdocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/), a static site generator developed using python, primarily for writing project documentations.